Flutter Web - JS Interop Listener (js-> js_interop)
I am trying to listen to the value of a scroll listener in my index.html file (named dartCtrlWheelEventHandler which returns a number value). My Flutter web app is able to listen to the value with the js library:
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('dartCtrlWheelEventHandler')
external set dartCtrlWheelEventHandler(Function f);

dartCtrlWheelEventHandler = allowInterop(_ctrlWheelEventHandler);

  void _ctrlWheelEventHandler(num deltaY) {
    setState(() {
      // Adjust the zoom level based on deltaY
      _zoomLevel += deltaY > 0 ? -0.1 : 0.1;
      // Clamp the zoom level between min and max values
      _zoomLevel = _zoomLevel.clamp(0.5, 2.0);
    });
    print(_zoomLevel);
  }

Due to its imminent deprecation, I am trying to utilize the js_interop library instead of the js alternative. I cannot figure out how to implement the equivalent allowInterop to have a dart function called whenever the js listener function detects a scroll.

Figured it out! For js_interop: Instead of "Function," use "JSFunction." Then instead of "allowInterop" use ".toJS"
@JS('dartCtrlWheelEventHandler') external set dartCtrlWheelEventHandler(JSFunction f);

dartCtrlWheelEventHandler = _ctrlWheelEventHandler.toJS; 

